# selecting content to display based on user in Grails with Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a Grails app that has a Domain for `People`, `Location`, `Pictures` and `Users`.  Controllers and Views have been generated.   I have my index page `sec:tagged` so that the admin can see the controllers to upload files, create data, and users.

Users have a username, password and location.  When a user logs in I want them to see the files that pertain to their location. There can be multiple users attached to a location. But I want every user with that location to see the associated files. I stared with the `@Secure` but moved to the `sec:` tags. Now I just need to limit the display of files based on location. Any advice?

Here is the code I have so far for the user display

```
<sec:access expression="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">

<% def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentlyLoggedInUser()
def aPerson = user.person
def locations = Location.findAllByPerson(aPerson)
locations.each ${it.picture}    %>

<g:select name="picture" from="${aPerson.all()}"/>
</sec:access>
```

This displays nothing on the User page.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to look at using the springSecurityService to get the current user (getCurrentUser()), this way you can then do a dynamic query based on the users location?

Comment: How is your domains look like?

Comment: This is what I have so far  <sec:access expression="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">

<% def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentlyLoggedInUser()
def aPerson = user.Person
def locations = Location.findAllByPerson(aPerson)
locations.each ${it.report} %>

<g:select name="report" from="${aPerson.all()}"/>
</sec:access>      // I have this in the index

Comment: Please add the code into the question.

Comment: I think your issue is that you're trying to print the location.picture inside your script block. I'm not sure you can escape the block using the ${} syntax. I would suggest using a g:each tag to iterate through your pictures outside the script block, eg. <g:each in="${locations}" var="img"> ${img} </g:each> . Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, avoid `<% %>` at all costs.  Secondly, I have no idea what you think this code is supposed to be doing:

```
<g:select name="picture" from="${aPerson.all()}"/>
```

Lastly, it would help to see your Domain code to understand the actual relationship between all of them.  But moving forward with what you have provided, I'd approach it like this:

controller

```
def someAction() {
    def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentlyLoggedInUser()
    def aPerson = user.person
    def locations = Location.findAllByPerson(aPerson)
    [aPerson: aPerson, locations: locations]
}
```

view

```
<!-- only use the expression tag if you actually need an expression -->
<sec:ifAllGranted roles='ROLE_USER'>
  <g:each in="${locations}" var="location">
     <!-- do something with each location -->
  </g:each>

  <g:select name="picture" from="${aPerson.all()}"/>
</sec:ifAllGranted>
```